# C++) How to use other class' method from a class?

Tags: c++

Here, I want to use class var's method "whats" from class func.
How to call it, 1. in one script 2. separated into several class files.
Help!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node {
public:
    int y;
    node(int x){
        y = x;
    }
};
class var {
public:
    node* head = new node(2);
    int whats(int s) {
        return s + head->y;
    }

};
class func {
public:
    int v;
    func(int vv) {
        v = vv;
    }
    //funcname(int x);
};
int main() {
    func fun = func(0);
    var vars;
    vars.head->y = 2;
    //cout << fun.funcname(3);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Edited! I expect the complied result shows up 5. + No inheritance.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. `whats()` is not a function. It is a class method. To use a class method you must have an instance of the class, whose method you will invoke. There is no instance of `var`, in `func`, so you need to figure out how to make that part happen, first.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You cannot execute methods in headers, but anywhere else, it's simple, the way you access it is by creating a new pointer.

```
var * v = new var();
v->whats(1);
```

Note that this is prone to memory leaks, so consider deleting pointers after you use them, like

```
delete ( v );
```

Comment: why `new` ? yes this is prone to memroy leaks, so one should simply do `var v; v.whats(1);`

Comment: @idclev463035818 it will cause a null ptr exception, if it manages to compile in the first place.

Comment: what ? why will it cause a nulll ptr exception?

Comment: @idclev463035818 my bad, didn't notice that you're not using a pointer D:

Comment: This wasn't my question.